# Is there an English idiom that means "you can always find a law to convict anyone"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

There's an infamous phrase in Russian (attributed to Stalin's Chief Prosecutor Vyshinsky):

> "Был бы человек, а статья найдется"

Translated literally, this means

> "if there was a man, an article *{{meaning "a law to convict him under"}}* will be found"

Is there an idiom in English that reflects the same meaning? (e.g., "we, as the judicial power, can find an appropriate legal excuse to convict anyone and everyone")

Comment: I don't know an idiom for this, but the topic has been explored by Harvey Silverglate in his book **[Three Felonies A Day: How the Feds Target the Innocent](http://www.amazon.com/Three-Felonies-Day-Target-Innocent/dp/1594035229)**. His thesis is that everyone in the US unwittingly commits crimes every day that could be, and sometimes are, used to prosecute them.

Comment: I'm well aware of the book, but don't recall him using any idioms on the topic

Comment: “It is easy to find a stick to beat a dog” does not specifically refer to the judiciary, but otherwise conveys the same meaning.

Comment: Not an idiom, but the famous quote from Cardinal Richelieu might be used to express that sentiment: "If you give me six lines written by the hand of the most honest of men, I will find something in them which will hang him."

Comment: [John Stossel - Illegal Everything](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBiJB8YuDBQ&list=PL3nwqCE5fVLdu9ogVRGnyQZLa3MRbMVn7&index=1)

Comment: My own version: "Show me a saint, and I'll prove he's a devil".

Comment: ""Must be guilty of something" is what comes to my mind.   There is AP Herbert's report of the case *[Rex v. Haddock](http://surelysomemistake.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/r-v-haddock-is-it-free-country.html)* where the Court of Appeal said "It is a principle of English law that a person who appears in a police court has done something undesirable" but sadly this is fictional. By contrast the real Scots law *[declaratory power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaratory_power)*  allows the the court to declare behaviour to be criminal activity, even if it had not been previously defined as criminal.

Comment: A more idiomatic version of your translation would be a good English phrase: "For every man, there's a law to convict him under". It's clear, and it's fresh; the only real improvement would be seeing if a non-gender-specific version could be constructed while not being barbarous. Why would you want to use an existing cliche when the translated phrase is so nice?

Comment: The term "Kangaroo court" is somewhat related.

Comment: @Henry - It's worth noting that the US constitution does not allow such judicial ("common law") definitions of criminality.  A person cannot (in theory) be convicted of a crime unless a law defining the crime had been passed by the appropriate legislative body prior to the commission of the crime.

Comment: @HotLicks: Unfortunately, regulatory agencies often craft rules which are afforded as much authority as legislated statutes, but which aren't bound by the same restrictions as the legislature.  There have been a number of cases in which a regulatory agency has stated that something is legal to manufacture, and then reversed that ruling to not only forbid future manufacture but also to declare that existing items were contraband and must be destroyed without compensation.

Comment: "let him who is without sin cast the first stone" :-)

Comment: Continually trying to charge someone with something when there is no proof that they've done anything wrong is often referred to metaphorically as "a witch hunt."

Comment: @Pharap "Kangaroo Charges" perhaps? Let's coin it, go go go

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**A good prosecutor can indict a ham sandwich.**

The original phrase, [attributed to New York judge Sol Wachtler](http://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/indict_a_ham_sandwich/), from 1985, went something like this:

> “[If a district attorney wanted, a grand jury would] indict a ham sandwich.”

It was immortalized in the Tom Wolfe novel "Bonfire of the Vanities" (1987).

The phrase succinctly summarizes the state of legal affairs where a prosecutor can find some law written somewhere that even the most well-behaved citizen has broken.

---

Update

For those who think that being indicted is less severe than being convicted, you may want to become familiar with the process and its consequences, as described in **[Ham Sandwich Nation: Due Process When Everything Is a Crime](http://columbialawreview.org/ham-sandwich-nation_reynolds/)** (Glen Reynolds, Columbian Law Review, July 8, 2013) on how prosecutors might pick the laws they choose to indict under in order to obtain likely conviction. In the end, this can make indictment vs. conviction a distinction without a difference. This is exactly what the OP is describing.

Taking the quote from the article:

> It would then be up to the junior prosecutors to figure out a plausible crime for which to indict him or her. The crimes were not usually rape, murder, or other crimes you’d see on Law & Order but rather the incredibly broad yet obscure crimes that populate the U.S. Code like a kind of jurisprudential minefield: Crimes like “false statements” (a felony, up to five years), “obstructing the mails” (five years), or “false pretenses on the high seas” (also five years). The trick and the skill lay in finding the more obscure offenses that fit the character of the celebrity and carried the toughest sentences. The, result, however, was inevitable: “prison time.”

So, if the prosecutor wanted to convict someone, then some obscure crime with a severe penalty would be found that would apply.

Comment: Perhaps note that this poor ham sandwich is the subject of many ridiculous ongoings. In other words, it is the way that the sentence uses this colloquial lunch staple that makes this a phrase that most English speakers would understand as meaning "The law/courts can convict anyone of anything."

Comment: Keep in mind that an indictment is not the same as a conviction, an indictment just means there is sufficient evidence for an actual trial to proceed. The trial will establish guilt or innocence. So there is a subtle nuance to this phrase that may not be apparent to people unfamiliar with the purpose of a grand jury.

Comment: @Necreaux Or possibly just a subtle nuance that highlights a difference between the Russian and the US judicial system. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I think this really doesn't have the same meaning.

Comment: @Necreaux: and as I understand it (not being from the US, my knowledge of grand juries is not deep), they don't even *really* imply that there's sufficient evidence for trial. The evidence isn't contested before the grand jury, they just get the prosecutor's claims. So all it really amounts to is that the prosecutor claims there's sufficient evidence for trial, and all a grand jury does is ensure that the prosecutor isn't talking arrant gibberish, and that the case and any witnesses seem faintly plausible. The ham sandwich can still get a judge to dismiss the case in pretrial motions :-)

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the phrase means. When I've seen it used, it's not saying "there's always _some_ law that you can find someone guilty of," it's saying "grand juries will do whatever a prosecutor wants them to" (instead of making independent decisions, they'll indict anyone for anything if the prosecutor wants them to do that). I read the question as saying that there's *some* charge you can hang on anyone; this phrase says you can get a grand jury to hang *any* charge on anyone.

Comment: As is pointed out elsewhere, this is very much an American expression, not commonly heard in other English-speaking countries.

Comment: I would also point out that most Americans do not really know what a grand jury is or how it works as evidenced in many books, TV shows etc. so that nuance may be lost on most Americains.

Comment: The last quote is highly misleading without context. In the original article it's about jocular game played by prosecutors, not about real-life indictments, as implied by answer.

Answer (score 31):

The one that springs to mind immediately is:

> If you give me six lines written by the hand of the most honest of men, I will find something in them which will hang him.[1](http://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Cardinal_Richelieu)

It is translated from French, allegedly by Cardinal Richelieu, and I have seen it used in English to indicate how easy it is for authorities to secure a conviction on vague charges.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. The indicting a ham sandwich example is known, but sounds American, to British ears. This is the example which I've heard most commonly in Britain.

Comment: Warren Buffett: "If a cop follows you for 500 miles (800 kilometers), you’re going to get a ticket,”

Answer (score 30):

How about **"Any excuse will serve a tyrant"**

Added at the end of (one of the variants of) "The Wolf and the Lamb", as the moral of the story.  Written by Aesop (620-550 BCE) this is a well-known fable where a victim (the lamb) is falsely accused and killed (by the wolf) despite a reasonable defence.

> from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_and_the_Lamb)
>
> - Down the centuries the various interpreters of the fable have applied it to the injustices of their time. In the extended treatment by the 15th century Scottish poet Robert Henryson in his Moral Fables a picture of widespread social breakdown is depicted. The Lamb appeals to natural law, to scripture, and to statutory law, and is answered with perversions of all these by the Wolf.

Answer (score 22):

**Guilty until proven innocent** is a newish twist on an old adage.

It's the title of a 2010 film, it appears quite commonly on the internet (almost half a million Google hits), and Boris Johnson has called for a switch in the terrorist laws to a position that the Guardian labels using this expression [[Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/politics/2014/aug/25/boris-johnson-britons-visiting-iraq-syria-presumed-terrorists)].

Comment: Actually, the phrase "guilty until proven innocent" has been around for decades, at least.  NGram finds at least two dozen credible uses prior to 1955, at which time the frequency of use increases sharply (and virtually monotonically).

Comment: ...Worrying ...

Comment: In some countries, the legal system revolves around the central idea that the defendant is "Guilty until proven innocent." This means that all of those accused of crimes are seen to be guilty, and the defendant (the accused and his lawyer) have to prove to the jury otherwise. The Prosecution will try to keep their stance that the defendant is guilty. Other western countries (i.e. America, Australia, U.K.) assume the opposite. The defendant is assumed innocent, and the law has to prove to the jury that he is guilty.

Comment: I don't think this answer is quite fitting; the question refers specifically to the fact that for everyone, a legal reason can be found to consider them guilty. "Guilty until proven innocent." is decidedly different in that it specifically expresses that no reason is required to consider someone guilty. It does not make any statement on whether such a reason can or cannot be found, as the reason is irrelevant - what *is* required is a reason to consider someone *innocent*, and "guilty until proven innocent" does not make any statement on whether or not such a reason exists, either.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The usual [strong] connotation of the expression in Western states is that we are being at least threatened with a police state. Metaphorical broadening.

Answer (score 22):

Not sure how common it is, but I've heard **"Show me the man, and I'll show you the crime"** quite a few times.

Comment: [Lavrentiy Beria, head of Joseph Stalin's secret police in the old Soviet Union, declared, “**Show me the man, and I'll show you the crime.**”](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MwF-BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT70&dq=%22Show+me+the+man+and+I%27ll+show+you+the+crime%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MY8YVaGpNIrpaIjrgvgL&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Show%20me%20the%20man%20and%20I'll%20show%20you%20the%20crime%22&f=false). I kinda suspect this and OP's offering might just be different "translations" of the same "saying".

Comment: Or alternatively: "Find me the man, and I'll find you the crime"

Answer (score 15):

Not exactly an idiom, but a reasonably common phrase:

> Everyone's guilty of something.

Comment: This is similar, but I get the feeling it approaches the situation from the opposite aspect: the Russian saying (if I’m understanding it correctly) is a commentary on the _law_, not on the person. Even if someone leads a super-clean life, you can always find some statute or other that you can use to convict them under—you just have to dig hard and deep enough (in law texts, not into the actions of the person).

Comment: To turn it around and comment on the law, use it sarcastically: "Everyone's 'guilty' of something."

Answer (score 6):

Historically, most Anglophones probably haven't lived under despotic regimes characterized by autocratic misuse of the legal process, so it may be a cultural thing that we have no direct equivalent to OP's Russian "saying". But in similar contexts we (and indeed, power-abusing authorities) are quite likely to come up with...

> [**trumped-up charges**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22trumped-up%20charges%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (***trump** from French **tromper** = "to deceive"*)

Comment: This seems somewhat related, but IMHO addresses more an individual case, rather than the aggregate state of society implied in the initial idiom.

Comment: So this question isn't too broad? "So all possible answers here would be suggestions, with no meaningful way to identify a single unambiguously "correct" answer that we can all upvote." - FumbleFingers. Double-standards, yuck.

Comment: In the narrow sense, your historical remark is true, though one could argue that the relative proliferation of civil suing for everything and anything in many Western countries - including anglophone places - could very well lead to similar sayings. (I'm not claiming we face a lawsuit a day in these countries, just that there is an ever-growing number of somewhat absurd, yet successful, lawsuits that might well prompt a saying like the one described by the OP.)

Comment: @Mike: Surely you can see that most of the answers here are "idiomatic" and/or relatively commonly used expressions relevant to the requested context. But [your question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236164/) doesn't currently have any answers like that (because, I believe, there are none). You could argue that in neither case does the OP know in advance whether there is a relevant "idiomatic standard", but I think just looking at *how the questions are framed* suggests different perspectives/expectations anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This puts me in mind of the quote attributed to the Scottish judge, Robert McQueen, Lord Braxfield (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_McQueen,_Lord_Braxfield):

> - "Let them bring me prisoners, and I will find them law."

He is said to have been the model for Lord Weir in Robert Louis Stevenson's unfinished novel *Weir of Hermiston*.

One last quote from this caring and compassionate judge:

> - "Ye're a vera clever chiel, man, but ye wad be nane the waur o' a hanging."

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of "creative accounting"?  Based on that, we could coin a phrase, "creative policing," or "creative indicting."

*Throw the book at someone* means to apply all imaginable laws to get someone into as much trouble as possible.  Not exactly the same as your phrase, but related.

*Corruption?*