# What words would complete this thought on religion?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests, diction

> ...by the color of his skin or the _____ of his _____.

What words would go in the blanks to mean *his religion*, while still using *of his* in the phrase to maintain the flow?

*God of his faith* or *substance of his creed* are possible examples, although neither sits right with me.

Can someone suggest something a bit more articulate?

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I closevoted because I think the question is Too Broad. I could have gone for Primarily Opinion-based (or just "It's *writing advice*"), but I think there are relatively complex reasons why English doesn't tend to extend OP's *specific* idiomatically established construction to other "lifestyle of choice/accident of birth" contexts where the intention is to convey ***complete neutrality*** (to the fact of such differences existing at all, as well as the relative merits of different subsets within any particular classification category).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, in which case, no one should ever ask for synonyms -- because it's too broad. In which case, why is it a tag? In fact, why is "word-choice" even a tag? Most questions of "word-choice" should be closed if broadness of answers is your concern.

Comment: But you're not *asking* for a "synonym". You're asking for a pair of words that could be used to replicate the "racial" *colour/skin* construction using a "religious" *faith/god* word-pair. Everyone has ***skin*** (of one colour or another), so it's quite reasonable to say anyone''s *particular* skin colour is irrelevant. But not everyone has ***religious faith*** in the first place, and the vast majority of those that do obviously believe *their* God is "real, true" and that everyone else is wrong. And they're making a *choice*, not simply "born different".

Comment: What does that have to do with finding a phrase containing "of his" that signifies "religion"? It's the reason there's a tag "phrase-requests".

Comment: Mike, in my understanding the "phrase-requests" tag is for identifying *established usages*. The way I see it, there is no established usage relating to religion with the *colour of skin* format (perhaps for the reasons I've suggested). So all possible answers here would be *suggestions*, with no meaningful way to identify a single unambiguously "correct" answer that we can all upvote. As of right now there's only one answer - but it includes 8 different suggestions anyway. Effectively what we have here is a "beauty contest", which isn't really the way SE sites are supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love this kind of question. I get the poetic effect you're going for. I'll take a stab at it:

"...name of his deity."

"...direction of his prayers."

"...author of his holy book."

"...receiver of his worship."

"...words of his hymns."

"...aspect of his church."

"...nature of his religious beliefs."

"...sign of his prophet."

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? Downvoting without explanation is really unconstructive.